# Vertically Shrink image

Tags: html, css, image

I have an image that I want to make the height 75% of what it normally would be. I am using a responsive layout, so this cannot be done using fixed pixel heights, etc. This will not work as a background image, so I am wondering if there is a similar effect to using `background-size: 100% 75%;` but that will work on an `img` tag? I would like to achieve this using just CSS.

Edit:

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/x9n0t4bu/

HTML:

```
<div id="disp">
                <a href="google.com"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/
demo-10/data/images/dock.jpg"></a>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
#disp{
    margin-top:-17.9px;
    width: 100%;
}

#disp img{
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Please add codes for better understanding.

Comment: Are you wanting the image to be 75% of itself or of it's parent?

Comment: @Sneha Bharti I have added code, although the situation should be quite generic.

Comment: @Pete I want the image to have the height be 75% of itself, and the width to be 100% of itself.

Comment: In which case I would use the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use transform: scale, this should make the image 75% of its original size.

```
-webkit-transform: scale(0.75); /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
-moz-transform: scale(0.75); /* FF3.5+ */
-ms-transform: scale(0.75); /* IE9 */
-o-transform: scale(0.75); /* Opera 10.5+ */
transform: scale(0.75);
```

```css
#disp{
    margin-top:-17.9px;
    width: 100%;
}

#disp img{    
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 0.75); /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
    -moz-transform: scale(1, 0.75); /* FF3.5+ */
    -ms-transform: scale(1, 0.75); /* IE9 */
    -o-transform: scale(1, 0.75); /* Opera 10.5+ */
    transform: scale(1,0.75);
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="disp">
                <a href="google.com"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/
demo-10/data/images/dock.jpg"></a>
            </div>
```

Comment: That is very close to what I am looking for, but this is also decreasing the width of the image. I want the width to remain the same, the height to be reduced.

Comment: I was able to make your example work by changing `scale` in each line to be `scaleY`.

Comment: If you keep the height the same, the aspect ratio will be wrong and the image may get distorted

Comment: Yeah, the image would be squished.

Comment: In my particular case I want the image to be squished, so yes that is what happens in that case.

Comment: Just edited it, it will now be 75%height and 100% width of original, and it will fill up 100% width of the div.